# JavaScript How to init TPDCard in Tappay

Tags: javascript, tap-payment

I want to write a [TapPay Library](https://docs.tappaysdk.com/tutorial/en/home.html) Web version.

I want to test a function that can use hardcore number to getPrime,

but every sample is create fields waiting user to input cardNumber.

I dont want to create any fields.

Just like this Kotlin sample. Is there has similar code in JavaScript?

```
    val cardNumber= StringBuffer(cardNumber)
    val dueMonth= StringBuffer(dueMonth)
    val dueYear= StringBuffer(dueYear)
    val ccv= StringBuffer(ccv)
    val card = TPDCard(context, cardNumber, dueMonth, dueYear, ccv).onSuccessCallback { prime, _, _, _ ->
                onSuccess(prime)
            }.onFailureCallback { status, errorMessage ->
                onFailure(errorMessage )
            }
            card.createToken(/* geoLocation = */ "Unknown")
```